# Select 2 not populating options, but return data is correct format?

Tags: php, json, jquery-select2

I have this jQuery

```
$('#document').ready(function(){
        $('#page_posts_select').select2({
            ajax: {
                url: "admin/pages/get_posts_for_select",
                type: "GET",
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
        });
    })
```

And the data logged in the console is like this:

```
{"results":[{"id":"1","text":"Option1"},{"id":"2","text":"Option2"}]}
```

My server side function looks like this:

```
$results = $this->posts_model->get_all_posts_for_dropdown();
    $select_results = array();
    foreach($results as $result){
        $select_results[] = array('id'=>$result->post_id, 'text'=>$result->title);
    }
    $output = new stdClass();
    $output->results = $select_results;
    echo json_encode($output);
```

Why does my select list not display any options, shouldn't it display the Option1 and Option2 in the dropdown? Is there some extra attribute that the ajax needs?

According to the research I have done all I should need is the correct returned format, being the object with the "results" attribute holding the array of "id" and "text" fields.

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved this, I did not include `dataType: 'json'` for the ajax attributes.